# Get Fill Color of Rectangle in Coded UI for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, coded-ui-tests

I'm writing some Coded UI tests for a simple application and cannot seem to get the code to find Rectangle objects. In the specific case I have the color of the rectangle presents whether two strings match or not based on the fill color.

When trying to find the rectangle using the Coded UI Test Builder the parent object is being found instead of the rectangle. I am also seeing that the code returns that it is unable to find the rectangle when I have it search manually.

Below is the XAML for the page I am trying to test against:

```
<Page
x:Class="TestApp.ButtonTester"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Title Panel -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="pageTitle" Text="Button Tester" Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">
        <StackPanel Name="buttonValidator">
            <TextBlock Name="verifyText" Text="Hi" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource LargeText}"/>
            <Button Name="changeText" Content="Change Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="changeText_Click"/>
            <TextBox Name="guessText" Text="Enter Text From Above" TextAlignment="Center" GotFocus="guessText_GotFocus" KeyDown="guessText_KeyDown"/>
            <Button Name="verifyMatch" Content="Verify" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="verifyMatch_Click"/>
            <Rectangle Name="matchAlert" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And here is the test code I currently have:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestVerifyIncorrect()
    {
        UITestControl verifyMatch = new UITestControl(myApp);
        verifyMatch.TechnologyName = "UIA";

        verifyMatch.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Button");
        verifyMatch.SearchProperties.Add("AutomationId", "verifyMatch");

        Gesture.Tap(verifyMatch);

        UITestControl matchAlert = new UITestControl(myApp);
        matchAlert.TechnologyName = "UIA";

        matchAlert.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Rectangle");
        matchAlert.SearchProperties.Add("AutomationId", "matchAlert");

        var fillColor = matchAlert.GetProperty("Fill");
    }
```

I am also seeing the Test Builder unable to detect a rectangle even when it is being used as a control.

I also looked into the Rectangle class vs the Button class and it appears the first common link in their inheritance chains is with Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement. I'm unaware of what type of ojects the Coded UI is able to detect to know if that may be the cause of the issue.